# Do I need to protect my leather saddle from the sun?

Tags: saddle, leather

Most questions about leather saddles seem to be about keeping them dry, but what about *too* dry?

I just bought a new bike with a Brooks B-17. I've applied proofide and I will be getting a cover to protect it from the rain (it's stored outside unfortunately). However, currently it's extremely hot and sunny where I live. Should I be getting a cover more urgently to protect the saddle from hot sun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The leather's greatest enemy is moisture, not water. Leather becomes mouldy if it is wet for a long time. Don't let that happen.
It may lose its colour when exposed to the sun, but under the tight plastic cover it may become wet - do not leave your bike in bright sunshine all day.
Quick rain may leave spots, but won't destroy the leather.
Dry heat can lead to excessive drying - therefore shoes or other leather  items must not be dried on the heater.
Take care of your wonderful saddle. I don't know what leather preservatives you can buy in your area - check what they have for leather clothes. If there is any horse riding accessories shop*, especially old fashioned, they may have best solutions.
Use this protection after drying and before winter storing.

---

supplement
* horses and jockeys are sweating, horse saddles and harnesses are precious - they must be good at caring for the leather.

If your bike is completely **stainless** and you can safely leave it outside, do not leave it with a leather saddle.
Too much fresh air and changes in the weather are bad for the leather.

If you need the best **sun protection** - think about an airy cotton or linen bag.

The best place to store leather is a wooden, clean, closed wardrobe.

Don't panic - I've described the best practices - you don't have to do this every day, just do the right thing.

Comment: Saddle soap should work equally good no matter if it's a bike or a horse saddle, as long as it's leather. Good idea with horse riding shop.

Answer (score 5):

I'd think a white opaque plastic bag over saddle would do fine.  The leather has to breathe - if you wrap it tightly then it might grow mould.

You might have to treat your saddle leather a little more frequently if it lives in the sun/heat a lot.

Ideally, store your bike inside, a garage, or at least under some rain protection.  A balcony/porch/etc is better than out in the weather.   A wall-hook or lift might let you utilise unusable space.